# Straighce logger issue

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have Straighce.dll in my project. I can not find any source code in the WEB.
I need to limit the size of the log files
Any body could help or supply the source code of this old logger?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Straighce Project is now hosted in [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/straighce). You can browse the source code there.

Comment: Hi rejeem_cariazo
I saw this link, but there is no code to download or view.

Comment: click on browse-code > straighce > straighce > straighce then you can see the codes